# Как найти все символические ссылки (symlinks) на файл/папку в Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, файловая-система, ntfs, symlinks

Как найти все символические ссылки (`symlinks`) на целевой файл/папку в **Windows**, используя только стандартные функции ОС?

P.S.
В качестве побочного вопроса интересует также, как эта проблема может быть решена и в **UNIX**?

Вопрос, разумеется, о том, как это сделать, не прибегая к сторонним утилитам (пусть и встроенным, вроде `mklink` или `ls`), равно как и к перебору всех файлов на предмет того, не являются ли они ссылками.

Comment: Я сильно сомневаюсь, что кто-то кроме симлинка знает о том, куда он ведет.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167363/how-to-find-all-the-hard-and-symbolic-links-to-a-file-folder-windows-and-unix

Answer (score 5):

Только получить все симлинки со всех разделов, как сказано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483010/how-to-list-all-symbolic-links-on-an-ntfs-filesystem), потом просто проверить, ссылаются ли они на данный файл/папку. Сам файл не знает о симлинках, ссылающихся на него. В WinAPI не предусмотрен такой функционал, поэтому это единственный вариант это перебор.

**UPDATE**

Как написал @ixSci, в UNIX дела обстоят схожим образов

Comment: Но ведь, если я правильно понимаю, там предлагается сначала проанализировать каждый файл на предмет того, не является ли он символической ссылкой...
Нет ли какого-нибудь иного способа получить этот список?

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous фс нигде не хранит их список

Comment: В ответ можно добавить, что в UNIX дела обстоят схожим образом.

Comment: @Flowneee а где, в таком случае, ФС хранит список hard link'ов, которые можно получать от WinAPI посредством `FindFirstFileName` и `FindNextFileName`?

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous не знаю точно как оно сделано в NTFS, но скорее всего где-то в Master File Table.

Answer (score 3):

> В качестве побочного вопроса интересует также, как эта проблема может быть решена и в UNIX?

как и везде: поиском.

в [*posix*-варианте](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), насколько мне известно, никаких вспомогательных средств по этому поводу не предусмотрено.

в [варианте](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) для операционной системы *gnu* имеется опция `-samefile файл`, позволяющая находить *hardlink-и* и *symlink-и* (с опцией `-L`).

пример для иллюстрации:

```
$ mkdir test && cd test
$ touch file other.file
$ ln file file.hard
$ ln -s file file.soft
$ find . -samefile file
./file.hard
./file
$ find -L . -samefile file
./file.hard
./file.soft
./file
```